# Is there a way to subscribe to a The Graph subgraph?

Tags: uniswap, events, swaps, the-graph, graphql

I want to use GraphQL subscription to be able to watch for all changes in the liquidity pools. Is there a way to do this with The Graph or another possible option?

[image]

Comment: Note that you can subscribe to these events using your own Ethereum node. No TheGraph needed.